# return object after null checking through if

Tags: return, blazor

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse<Product>> GetProductAsync(int productId)
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<Product>()
    {
        Data = await _context.Products.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == productId)
    } ;

    if ( response.Data == null )
    {
        response.Success = false ;
        response.Message = "Sorry, but this product does not exist." ;
    }
    else
        return response ;

    return response ;
}
```

I made `productservice.cs file`. The above code is the part of it which will return one product class in Gerelic T.

First, I find matched productid in db. Then, null check. If it is not null it will return response, OK.

I thought at first I will return response as one product to `Task` `T`, all code might be good.

But I faced an error in the last line, so I put again `return response`. Then the error sign was disappeared.

I think this might be wrong and weird, even though there is no error anymore. How can I solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: you should return a 404 (resouce not found) if the product does not exist a http 200 indicates a successful operation ie: with data

Comment: If you want to use return codes, then return a 204 (NO CONTENT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you faced probably was something like `not all code paths return a value`. Since your method returns a typed value, and you are using `if-else` statement -- you have to provide returning value both in `if` and `else` clauses.

1. Extend your `ServiceResponse<T>` with a constructor that receives some arguments.
2. Refactor your method in order to stress your `product` variable for better readability.
3. Return `ServiceResponse` using newly-created constructor.

Unfortunately, I can't test it right now to be sure 100%, but you can give it a try.

```
class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ServiceResponse( T data, string message = "success" )
    {
        Data = data;
        IsSuccess = data != null;
        Message = data == null ? "Sorry, but this product does not exist." : message;
    }
}


public async Task<ServiceResponse<Product>> GetProductAsync( int productId )
{
   var product = await _context.Products.Where( p => p.Id == productId).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
   return new ServiceResponse<Product>( product );
}
```

**Remarks**

1. We don’t have to provide 2nd argument into the constructor while returning the response since it already has the default value defined for the `message` in the constructor. But you still can do that!
2. I also set default value for the `message` there if `data == null`. Actually, it can be removed if you wish!
3. `IsSuccess` is also being regulated by `data` in the constructor of `ServiceResponse<T>`

**UPD: Tested**

```
if ProductId == 1

{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Test1"
  },
  "isSuccess": true,
  "message": "success"
}
```

---

```
if ProductId == 2 (which is out of list)

{
  "data": null,
  "isSuccess": false,
  "message": "Sorry, but this product does not exist."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after u instances a new ServiceResponse you have to create the build the Data, so you have to do response.Data = new Product();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).